# C++: Converting a double/float to string, preserve scientific notation and precision

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert double/float numbers to string. Some of these numbers contain scientific notation "e", and I want to preserve it after the conversion. I searched through google and stackoverflow and didn't find a matching answer to my use case.

Here are some examples and expected output:

```
input: 1.7976931348623157e+308
output: "1.7976931348623157e+308"
```

Here is a full `main.cc` file that can be compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string ToString(T value) {
  std::stringstream out;
  out << std::fixed;
  out << value;
  return out.str();
}

int main () {
    double mydouble = 1.7976931348623157e+308;
    std::cout << ToString(mydouble) << std::endl;
}
```

--- Update 11:17AM -----

There is no more weird characters after running my standalone code above, but the output is a long string-formatted float:

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```

Not the expected "1.7976931348623157e+308".

-------- Outdated ----------------

But the output is a weird string:

```
"179769313486231610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««««««««««îþîþîþîþ"
```

Comment: what is the type that your function returns?? share a verifiable example!

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's `std::string`, I'm editing the question right away

Comment: now, the only thing to make this a *verifiable* example is showing how you call `ToString` and what you do with the result to get output.

Comment: `ToString` looks okay; I suspect it may the way you're calling it.

Comment: I called it with `ToString(myDoubleNumber)`. I tried debugging it and the passed in `value` in the `ToString` function looks good. Then after `out << value`, the `out` contains the aforementioned weird string.

Comment: @benjaminz you were doing so good, please do add a `main()...` function that shows of an example that we can compile to recreate!

Comment: Trying to get IOStreams to produce dependably formatted decimals is like trying to get a high school student to post a decent Stack Overflow question - borderline im-bloody-possible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not sure if being helpful or plain mean to them highschoolers :)

Comment: [Not reproduced on GCC](http://ideone.com/t1yPBq). What compiler are you using, and does your code contain anything except what you showed above?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm spoiled by how easy it is to convert between types in dynamic-typed languages. Sorry if my question appears to be juvenile.

Comment: anyway, @benjaminz, I can't reproduce. My output is `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000`, which looks darn right

Comment: @benjaminz don't be spoiled; this looks like something has a bug, and it's not C++ as language, but something else.

Comment: This is not the whole code, it is a relatively large file. I'm building something on top of someone else's work. The `ToString` function is written by someone else. Please allow me a minute or so to reproduce a minimal and compile-able code snippet, I'll be write back.

Comment: Oh, come on. I'm leaving this question now. I asked you 20 minutes ago for exactly that.

Comment: What sense does it make to show a different `ToString` implementation then the one you're using? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you so much for your patience. This `ToString` function ***is*** the one I'm using, not a recreated one. I just extracted it out of its original library code to better make my case. Please see the updated question body for a fully compile-able code snippet.

Comment: @benjaminz: _"Sorry if my question appears to be juvenile"_ It certainly doesn't; for some reason, this is quite tough in C++. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

Fixed isn't what you want if you want scientific notation. It's the opposite.

when I compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
inline std::string ToString(T value) {
    std::stringstream out;
    out << std::fixed;  
    out << value;
    return out.str();
}
int main()  
{
    double mydouble = 1.7976931348623157e+308; 
    std::cout << ToString(mydouble) << std::endl; 
}
```

I get

```
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```

which is right, which means there's a bug in your C++ compiler or standard library.

Comment: Ah! I see. I just commented out the `out << std::fixed` line and it worked like a charm. Thank you for your help and I appreciate your patience and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running fine. If you have crap values in the output maybe there is a stack corruption somewhere else.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline std::string ToString(T value) {
  std::stringstream out;
  out << std::fixed;  
  out << value;
  return out.str();
}

int main() {
  double mydouble = 1.7976931348623157e+308; 
  std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(mydouble) << '\n'; 
  std::cout << ToString(mydouble) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> 1.7976931348623157e+308
>   179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000

As it was pointed out by Marcus in previous comments you don't want to use std::fixed.